# Can I call a Client program inside my Server program?

Tags: java, swing, sockets, jframe, client-server

I am creating a program where my goal is that on a JButton click in a separate class called ClientChat, I create a server (in my ChatBoxServer class), and within that class, I call my Client program (ChatBoxClient class) to establish the connection. However, my program stalls when I try to call ChatBoxClient.java from ChatBoxServer.java. Is it possible to call my Client class within the Server class, or do I need to separately run the two programs?

ChatBoxServer:

```
public class ChatBoxServer implements ActionListener {

    private ServerSocket ss;
    private Socket s;
    private ObjectInputStream oin;
    private ObjectOutputStream oout;
    private ChatBox chat;
    private JButton hello;
    private String user;
    private String user2;
    private String host;

    public ChatBoxServer(String user, String user2, String host, int port) throws IOException{
        setUsers(user, user2);
        setHost(host);
        
        chat = new ChatBox();
        hello = chat.getSendButton();
        hello.addActionListener(this);
        createServer(port);
        
        
        
        if (!s.isConnected())
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot Connect", "Connection Status", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        
        
        chat.getChatArea().append("You are now connected!\tType quit to end chat.\n");

        readMessage();

    }



    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String outgoingMsg = "";

        try {
            outgoingMsg= chat.getSendField().getText(); 
            chat.getChatArea().append("<" + user +">:\t" + outgoingMsg + "\n");

            oout.writeObject(outgoingMsg);  
            oout.flush();  
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }  

        if (chat.getSendField().getText().equals("quit")) {
            try {
                s.close();
                oin.close();   
            } catch (Exception error) {
                System.out.println("Server side");
            }
        }
    }



    private void createServer(int port) throws IOException {
        ss=new ServerSocket(port); 
        ClientChatTest cct = new ClientChatTest(user, user2, host, port);            
        s=ss.accept(); 
        oin=new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());  
        oout=new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());  
        
        


    }

    private void readMessage() {
        String incomingMsg = "";

        while (!incomingMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
            try {
                incomingMsg = (String) oin.readObject();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server Error", "Connection Status", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
            chat.getChatArea().append("<" + user2 + ">:\t" + incomingMsg + "\n");
        }

    }

    private void setUsers(String user, String user2) {
        this.user = user;
        this.user2 = user2;
    }
    
    private void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

}
```

ChatBoxClient:

```
public class ChatBoxClient implements ActionListener {

    Socket s;
    ObjectInputStream oin;
    ObjectOutputStream oout;
    private ChatBox chat;
    JButton hello;
    private String user;
    private String user2;
    
    public ChatBoxClient(String user, String user2, String hostname, int port) throws IOException {
        
        setUsers(user, user2);
        connection(hostname, port);

        chat = new ChatBox();
        hello = chat.getSendButton();
        hello.addActionListener(this);

        readMessage();
        
    }



    public void connection(String hostname, int port) throws IOException {

        s=new Socket(hostname, port);  
        oout=new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());  
        oin = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        
        if (s.isConnected()) {
            chat.getChatArea().append("You are now connected!\tType quit to end chat.\n");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        String outgoingMsg=""; 


        try {
            outgoingMsg = chat.getSendField().getText();  
            chat.getChatArea().append("<" + user2 + ">:\t" + outgoingMsg + "\n");
            oout.writeObject(outgoingMsg);
            oout.flush(); 


        } catch (IOException  e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }  

        if (chat.getSendField().getText().equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {

            try {
                oin.close();
                oout.close();
                s.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    private void readMessage() {
        String incomingMsg = "";

        while (!incomingMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
            try {
                incomingMsg = (String) oin.readObject();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server Error", "Connection Status", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
            chat.getChatArea().append("<" + user + ">:\t" + incomingMsg + "\n");
        }

    }
    
    private void setUsers(String user, String user2) {
        this.user = user;
        this.user2 = user2;
    }



}
```

Program works when I separately call the two classes, but not when I call the Client class within my Server class.

Comment: Think of email as a model. You have a client on your machine. On another machine (usually, but it could be on the same machine, but it is always another program) is the server. Your email client starts a connection to the server, the server sends data back. The connection usually closes. A few minutes later, the client connects to the server again, and gets more data. Sometimes the connection can remain open. However, at no time is the client and server the same program in this model.

Comment: Even in a chat program, the client should check the chat server by starting a connection and getting data back. At no time should the server initiate a connection. Once you get the simple model working, then you can experiment with more complex models.

Comment: One hint: I notice that you're using ObjectStream's. I avoid them like the plague. I've had nothing but trouble with them. First, they are java-specific. You can't make a client in another language and expect it to work. Second, it makes debugging the network protocol a royal pain. I use text-based protocols like xml or json. Then I can use telnet to debug the server without having to get a client working at the same time. And visa-versa.

Comment: As soon as I asked this question, I remember the general logic about client-server and realized it would make no sense for a client/server program be related to one program. Thanks. By the looks of my program, should I start my server on my computer, would I be able to interact with the server on another computer?

Comment: That's the whole idea of a tcp/ip socket. As long as the two machines can talk to each other, then hopefully your program will be able to do so.

Comment: I am not familiar with xml / json at all (2nd year CS major), how can I implement these protocols in java?

Comment: Search for them on the web. Xml files look something like ``<xml><user id="27" name="Fred Hogstedter"/></xml>`` I'm not as familiar with json, but many questions here contain json fragments.